# typo3 - don't copy inline child records

Tags: typo3

i want to copy a custom record 'article' that has several related inline child records (e.g. comment). My problem is that all inline child records are copied as well. In my example all comment records are copied as well when i copy the article record. How can i avoid this ?

I found out that i can avoid this behaviour whne moving a record with the following tca settings:

```
'behaviour' => array(
'disableMovingChildrenWithParent' => 1
),
```

Is there something similar for copying or some idea for a workaround ?

thanx !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Panade. I found a solution myself.

I used the processCmdmap hook in public function process_cmdmap() of sysext/core/Classes/DataHandling/DataHandler.php

I basically override $this->copyRecord($table, $id, $value, 1) and add a fifth parameter $overrideValues that contains an array with the fields i want to override, in my case 'comment' set to '0'. I do this only if the current table is my 'article' and the command is 'copy'.

Hope this helps out !

Answer (score 0):

One Way would editing this on Database Level. You could simply copy the Record to your new Page and then remove all referencing Links to its child in the Database. This can be extended to a Generic solution in form of an Extension. Maybe there is already such an Extension in the TYPO3 Ter Repository.

Another Solution (untested) could be the Export function on Page Base. There you can Define which elements you want to copy. It depends how the Comment and Article Records are stored, but maybe this is also a way to go.

If the Child Records are listed as Data Elements, you can also go to the List View and simply delete the Child Elements. This should also delete the Reference. This only works, if the Storage PID of the Child elements (comments) is the Page you put your main Element is on.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved the same thing very easy by setting **'setToDefaultOnCopy' in the TCA ctrl section** to the field of the inline records. This way the field is set to the default value (in most cases null) and is not copied aside with the parent record.

I have also evaluated the solution with the processCmdmap hook, which results in an empty inline records field on the parent record, but doesn't prevented the inline records from getting copied in general. In addition, in my case the copied child records still have their reference to the parent record set. **So the bottom line is that processCmdmap did not work for me, but TCA ctrl 'setToDefaultOnCopy' did the trick.**