# TYPO3 TCA field should have default value after copy

Tags: typo3

When I copy a record (e.g. a page), I would like the content of a field to (always) have the default value, not the value of the original record. But for my custom field, it always has the value of the original record and I can't find configuration to change this (e.g. in the [TCA documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Columns/Index.html)).

(This is not about how the field should be handled when translating, this is just about copying in the default language).

The field TCA is (simplified):

```
'my_field' => [
        'label' => 'Subnavigation',
        'l10n_mode' => 'exclude',
        'config' => [
            'type' => 'check',
            'default' => 0,
            'items' => [
                [
                    'check box 1',
                    ''
                ],
                [
                    'checkbox 2',
                    ''
                ],
            ],
        ],
    ],
```

`my_field` has the value 3, currently in the original record. The copied record should have the value 0.

Comment: Not posting as answer yet but have you tried [`useColumnsForDefaultValues`](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/UseColumnsForDefaultValues.html)? It sounds like default values can override the "previous" record values, which may be the source of a copy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several settings to influence the values of copies, the closest one seems to be [useColumnsForDefaultValues](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/UseColumnsForDefaultValues.html), I doubt though that it's exactly what you need.
Further options are [copyAfterDuplFields](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/CopyAfterDuplFields.html), [prependAtCopy](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/PrependAtCopy.html) and [hideAtCopy](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/main/en-us/Ctrl/Properties/HideAtCopy.html).
On the first linked page is also mentioned that default values in TSconfig can be set, those are only working when a record is opened and empty, so that is likely not solving the problem.
It might also be possible that you had [columnsOverrides](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/11.5/en-us/Types/Properties/ColumnsOverrides.html?highlight=columnsoverrides) in mind, I neither see though that this option meets the requirement.

I suppose you need to program a function for it, i.e. on base of the [ModifyRecordListRecordActionsEvent](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/11.5/en-us/Events/Events/Recordlist/ModifyRecordListRecordActionsEvent.html?highlight=copy).

Another option concerning programming would be [using a hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21555481/1019850) perhaps.

Comment: useColumnsForDefaultValues does not apply for copy.

Comment: prependAtCopy is not helpful for this - it only applies to the title.

Comment: I don't see that the desire is so straigthforward, even it looks reasonable. The options in my 2nd paragraph I added just to show that there are several options related to copies, I don't think that they could help. I think you've to code something but would be great if you could solve it without.